How to register tasks defined in a separate module with the celery_app fixture?
Celery documentation gives the following example to test a task with the celery_app pytest fixture :
def test_create_task(celery_app, celery_worker):
    @celery_app.task
    def mul(x, y):
        return x * y

    celery_worker.reload()
    assert mul.delay(4, 4).get(timeout=10) == 16

The task mul is defined in the test function and registered with the @celery_app.task decorator, provided by the celery_app fixture. How can I test tasks that are defined in another module ?
For example, in my tasks module, I define tasks and register them with my "usual" celery app:
from my_proj import app

@app.tasks()
def my_task(a, b):
   return ...

How can I register it with the celery_app object provided by the pytest fixture in the test function ?
